# PHP regular expression not working

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get those matches from an html file. It has several statements on them looking like this:

```
links(6)  = "chicas-con-juguetes.asp"
```

I am trying to extract them with this function:

```
    public static function extract_all_vid_links($html){
    $pattern="links([0-9])  = \"(.*).asp\"";
    preg_match_all( "/$pattern/i", $html ,$out, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    print_r($out);
    //    foreach($out as $values){
    //       echo $values[0]."<br/>";
    //   }
}
```

But it is not working!?!? why?

**modified:**

```
    $pattern="links\([0-9]\)  = \"(.*).asp\"";
    preg_match_all( "/$pattern/i", $html ,$out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to escape the `(` and `)` characters if you don't want to create a new match-group, take a look here: `links\(\d\)`.

Comment: hakre, that looks like an answer, not a comment :-)

Comment: Are there always two spaces? If not, use `\s*` in place

Comment: I thought about it...and no, it is irrelevant..Jeroens answer worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `(` and `)` characters if you don't want to create a new match-group, take a look here: `links\(\d\)`.

This does fix the problem you have described (so your description is wrong probably):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain;');


$html = 'links(6)  = "chicas-con-juguetes.asp"';

$pattern="links\(\d\)  = \"(.*).asp\"";
$r = preg_match_all( "/$pattern/i", $html ,$matches);

var_dump($r, $matches);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/916fdb), Output:

```
int(1)
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(37) "links(6)  = "chicas-con-juguetes.asp""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "chicas-con-juguetes"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think ur answer..worked.. why did you put \d and not [0-9]? does it matter

Comment: No, `\d` is exactly the same as `[0-9]`.

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd: Probably the string is not what you told it is. You probably want to scrape actual HTML and you only pasted what you see in the browser? Or your actual data differs in some other way?

Comment: I had to use the file get content to get the html.. but , you are right, I forgot to escape those () brackets..thats where the error lied

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/links\([0-9]+\)  = \"([^\.]*?).asp\"/i', $html, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

You need to escape the `()` characters. Also, I added a `+` after `[0-9]` so that numbers above 9 also work.